# Can a memory address which is not a multiply of 4 in 32 bit machine be reached?

Tags: assembly

I came across a piece of assembly code like following one

```
int fourth(char *str) {
return str[3];
{
0804834f <fourth>:
804834f: 55 push %ebp
8048350: 89 e5 mov %esp,%ebp
8048352: 8b 45 08 mov 0x8(%ebp),%eax
8048355: 83 c0 03 add $0x3,%eax
8048358: 0f be 00 movsbl (%eax),%eax
804835c: c9 leave
804835d: c3 ret
```

how come does it reach M[(%eax)+3] ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course. If you're only addressing a `byte`, then you have to be able to reach any address. (which is the case in the code snippet: `movsbl` is a byte access)

Furthermore, x86 allows misaligned memory access even for multi-byte words. (though usually at a performance cost) So even then, the address does not have to be a multiple of 4.

*The exception is with the SSE/AVX registers. Where you need to use explicit misaligned `mov` instructions for misaligned memory access.

Comment: As I understand from your reply, this kind of memory access is called misaligned memory access. Now that, word size of the machine 32byte, by any misaligned or normal memory access, we can fetch 4 successive bytes at one sitting. Am I right?

Comment: If you're accessing only 1 byte, it can't be misaligned since 1 byte is already the smallest unit. On 32-bit machines, yes you can fetch 4 bytes at a time. (actually more in some circumstances such as SIMD or 64-bit floating-point) But not all machines support misalignment. x86 does (in most cases).

Comment: unaligned is another word that is used for this kind of thing